# processing data and saving to db in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm learning Yii, and for my current project I need to do something like this: 
I have registration page where users enter their data and send it, Yii saves data exactly as user type it, so if I have field A and B, when user fill them it will be saved in database under A and B columns.
what I want to do is to take data from A and B, do some calculations and save output to C column (a and b shouldn't even exist) could You please tell me how to achieve such task?

Comment: Just declare `A` and `B` as public in your Model (`A` and `B` are not actual columns in the table). `C` is the column in your table. Then you can do like : `$model->C = $model->A + $model->B;`. Hopefully it will clear things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model:

```
public $A;
public $B;
```

In form:

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'A'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'A'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'A'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'B'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'B'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'B'); ?>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new Model();

    if (isset($_POST['Model'])) {
        //quite simple exaple
        $model->C = $_POST['Model']['A'] + $_POST['Model']['B'];
        $model->save();
    }

}
```

Or you can add method beforeSave() to your model, and do somethin like  V4KK4R says.)

Comment: Oh man, now thank You very much, i never worked on any framework, and these things are like black magic, but now it looks quite simple. Cheers guys!